# Huge app size of iOS build in react native

Tags: ios, react-native

**how to reduce app size in react-native ios**. In android i'll include the `"armeabi-v7a", "x86"` into build gradle file, its working fine. for ios?

***React-native : 0.57.7***

Comment: you can use bitcode to reduce the size - https://agostini.tech/2019/06/02/reduce-your-app-size-with-app-thinning/

Comment: in my Xcode `Enable Bitcode`, already set by **Yes** option.

Comment: https://agostini.tech/2019/06/02/reduce-your-app-size-with-app-thinning, already doing the same, but still compare to android it's much more(app size).

Answer (score 0):

You should not compare iOS app size with android! There are two different platforms. Second thing if you have used assets for the images and taken care of the app thinning then your app size will be different for the different devices. If you have uploaded any build on the test flight then from AppStoreConnect -> activity -> click on app icon -> click on App Store File Sizes and you will find different sizes for different devices. App size varies as per the device resolution.

Reference Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Now, To reduce the iOS build size you can take care of below things:

- Use Assets to manage the images. Do not put it in the folder or directory
- App thinning
- BitCode
- On demand resources are resources that are hosted on the App Store and your app downloads them when they’re needed. You add your resources to your asset catalogs and you tag them
- Run Time needed data should be kept at server side